# Get the about to be refunded qty in credit memo (partials refunds)

Tags: creditmemo

I am trying to generate an xml with the refunding data when the credit memo is generated.

The issue is that I cannot find any updated information for products if the qty has changed, I still get the original qty.

For example, in the credit memo, I change for 1 product the qty to 0, press the update qty button, but if I check it like this:

```
var_dump(Mage::getModel('sales/order_creditmemo_item/')->load($order_id)->getData('qty'))
```

I still get qty 1 for both. I want to get the qty about to be refunded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was looping over the products. This works:

```
$collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
foreach ($collection->getAllItems() as $item) {
       echo $item->getQty());
}
```

Comment: where you updated this code ?